# Can't get a lightbox to ignore the hidden elements on a jQuery dynamic list

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Nettus+ has this [nice jQuery code](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-jquery/) to filter out and show specific `<li>`s from a `<ul>` when a category is clicked. For example, when the 'design' link is clicked, only the 'design' `<li>`s are shown and the rest of the portfolio `<li>`s are hidden. However, when I combine it with a lightbox like Yoxview (image viewer jQuery plugin), the lightbox shows the `<li>`s from entire portfolio instead of just showing the specific category that was clicked on and filtered out.

**How can I get the the lightbox to show only the `<li>`s that are currently shown on the page and ignore the hidden `<li>`s?** Thanks for any help.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#filter a').click(function() {
        $(this).css('outline','none');
        $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

        if(filterVal == 'all') {
            $('ul#portfolio li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('ul#portfolio li').each(function() {
                if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});


<ul id="filter">  
     <li class="current"><a href="#">All</a></li>  
     <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>  
     <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>  
     <li><a href="#">CMS</a></li>  
     <li><a href="#">Integration</a></li>  
</ul>  

<ul id="portfolio">  
     <li class="cms integration">  
         <a href="#"><img src="images/a-list-apart.png" />A List Apart</a>  
     </li>  
     <li class="integration design">  
         <a href="#"><img src="images/apple.png" />Apple</a>  
     </li>  
     <li class="design development">  
         <a href="#"><img src="images/cnn.png" />CNN</a>  
     </li>  
     <li class="cms">  
         <a href="#"><img src="images/digg.png" />Digg</a>  
     </li>  
     <li class="design cms integration">  
         <a href="#"><img src="images/espn.png" />ESPN</a>  
     </li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get the the lightbox to show
>   only the `<li>`s that are currently
>   shown on the page and ignore the
>   hidden `<li>`s?

You can use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) filter selector that will only affect the elements that are visible something like this:

```
$('#ul_id li:visible')
```

The above selector will work only on those lis that are inside the parent element with id `ul_id` and are visible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using the :visible filter selector works, but when the lightbox pops up, it will show each li one at a time (the user has to click and close each one) instead of grouping them together so that they can be shown like a slideshow. The lightbox needs to be told the #ul_id so that it may group them together. So using #ul_id li:visible makes each li its own group. I don't understand why the lightbox is not ignoring the dynamically hidden elements in the ul.